# python - High time consumption and low efficiency in programming challenge

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I was trying to solve [this problem.](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/its-all-about-magic/)

> Recently Oz has found a magical string consisting of single digit "1". After experimenting on the string, Oz found a weird magical property of the string that is whenever he touches the string then each digit "1" of string changed to digit "0" and each digit "0" of string changed to "01". Oz found this property interesting and immediately asked a question to RK : "How many 1's and 0's will be in the magical string if he touches the string M times ?"

I wrote the following code for it:

```
l = [] #List of values

for x in range(int(raw_input())):
    l.append(int(raw_input()))

def after_touchs(n, string): #Main function finds the no. of 0's and 1's
    for x in range(n):
        string = string.replace('1', '2').replace('0', '01').replace('2', '0')

    return map(str, [string.count('1'), string.count('0')])

for num in l:
    print ' '.join(after_touchs(num, '1'))
```

I don't understand why this code is taking a lot of time. To me it seems perfectly normal and does not use much time. Since it didn't work on the site and ran the code with the interpreter on my computer and even an input of 50 seemed to large. Does the `string.replace` function take up too much time? So what alternatives can I use to it? Please help me reduce the time consumption and increase the efficiency of the code.

Comment: What is this code suppose to do?

Comment: string = string.replace('1', '2').replace('0', '01').replace('2', '0') is wrong (i think) : you replace 1 by 2 and juste after 2 by 0

Comment: return map(str, [string.count('1'), string.count('0')])  : is it "str" or "string" ?

Comment: @Benjamin `string` is the name of the variable. `str` is a built-in Python type.

Comment: The program only takes as long as it takes you to input for each int(raw_input()) called. You are typing in the range of values (for example 10), then have to type in 10 values for the program to finish.

Comment: Running an input of 20,000, it's taking me 0.18363189697265625/sec (l = [2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,1]*1000)

Comment: @Jamtot By an input of 50, I didn't mean the size of the list. I meant the highest value or the maximum value of 50 in the list.

Comment: You can use python profilers to look what takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Benjaming Don't you understand? If I convert '1' directly to '0' then it might affect when I convert '0' to '01' as all the '0's converted in that step will be converted to '01'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to count the number of 1 and 0, string manipulation is always heavy so I guess that's what slow you down.

```
number1 = 1
number0 = 0
for i in xrange(M):
    # 0 -> 01
    newnumber1 = number0
    # 1 -> 0 and 0 -> 01
    number0 += number1
    # we replace the number1 with the new number
    number1 = newnumber1
print "%d %d"%(number0,number1)
```

**EDIT**
There is a more efficient solution, that I saw in Tim Stopfer comment.
In fact, the number of 0's and 1's follow a fibonnacci sequence after the first change.
1: 101123
0: 011235
M: 012345

Which mean an O(1) solution would be:

```
if M>0:
    number1 = Fibo(M-1)
    number0 = Fibo(M)
```

But you have to approximate the value of the Fibonnacci Sequence with a formula found in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: That's an intelligent solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you edit the string each time.
You are basically implementing the fibonacci sequence and the 50th number is 
50 : 12586269025 = 52 x 11 x 101 x 151 x 3001

So you have a string of this length and you apply several string operations to it. 
This may cause the process to slow down.

I hope I could help.

Comment: Yes, but I still can't think of a better algorithm. Can you?

Comment: Since you don't need the actual string at the end I would try to calculate the number for the 0's and 1's.

Comment: I have an idea and a few test seem to indicate that I am right. Go like this: first find the n-th fibonacci number. The number of 0 is the fibonacci number right before that and the number of 1 is the second fibonacci number before that. So for 8 touches you would have a the fibonacci number 21 and 13 times 0 and 8 times 1

Answer (score 1):

according to the question the strings for the first 6 touches would look like this:

"1", "0", "01", "010", "01001", "01001010", "0100101001001"

and the counts will be
1 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 3, 3 5, 5 8
which reminds me of fibonacci series.
fibonacci numbers increase rapidly so you will end up with very long strings which take up a lot of memory and are slow to manipulate.

If you need speed then just calculate the fibonacci numbers.
You can also speed up the naive fibonacci by caching values that you already calculate so if you already know 4th and 5th elements of the series you can quickly calculate the 6th.

Answer (score 0):

public class MagicalString {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String modifiedString = touchTheString();
    countOneAndZero(modifiedString);

}

private static void countOneAndZero(String modifiedString) {

    Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

    char [] data = modifiedString.toCharArray();
    for(char c : data) {

        if(map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
        }else {
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);

    System.out.println(map.get('0'));
    System.out.println(map.get('1'));

}

static String touchTheString() {
    String input = "1";
    int touch = 5;

    while (touch != 0) {
        StringBuffer br = new StringBuffer();
        char[] temp = input.toCharArray();
        for (char c : temp) {
            if (c == '0') {
                input = br.append("01").toString();
            } else if (c == '1') {
                input = br.append("0").toString();
            }

        }

        touch--;
    }
    System.out.println(input);
    return input;
}
```

}

Comment: You have shown that you know how to solve that challeng in Java. Unfortunately the question is tagged [tag:Python] and also has a big *Python* in the title. It would also be much more helpful for others if you add some explanation to your code and why you think it is more efficient than OP's code.